# displaying a variable's value in a text box

Tags: javascript, code.org

```
var Stars = 0;

setText("Stars", Stars);

onEvent("FF1", "mouseover", function(event) {
  if (Star11 === true) {
    console.log("+1 star");
    var Stars = Stars + 1;
  }
  if (Star12 === true) {
    console.log("+1 star");
    var Stars = Stars + 1;
  }
```

I am trying to make a text box display the value of variable "Stars" after increasing that variable by 2. The text box is set at 0 and I am unable to get it to change based on the value of variable "Stars"

Edit: I have solved the issue

Comment: well I do not see you setting the value and you are going to have issues with using `var` which redefines scope inside of blocks.

Comment: lack of good tags is also going to kill the visibility of this question.

Comment: Please add the appropriate language and platform tags -  without them, this question is not answerable. Also, it would be best if you would provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including a *clear problem statement*, as it is not clear how the code you have tried is failing to meet your objective.

Comment: Why do you keep redeclaring stars?

Comment: The stars are declared when the user of the program clicks on a star. Clicking on a star is meant to add to the count

Comment: you would do well to hold off on asking questions on SO until you have a better grasp of JS in general. Honestly, from the code I see here, anyone who gives you a good answer is only going to confuse you. Start here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you can do something like this:

HTML:

```
<input id="stars" type="text" value=""/>
<button onclick="addStars()">
Click Me!
</button>
```

javaScript:

```
stars=0;
function addStars() {
    stars = stars + 1;
    document.getElementById("stars").value = "star "+ stars;
}
```